# How to make a nested route using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and Im trying to access the url `localhost:3000/users/add` but I'm not getting make that work.

Structure:

```
| index.js
| components/
|     App.js
|     Users/
|       Add.js
|       View.js
|       index.js
```

App.js:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/users" component={IndexUser} /> // import IndexUser from './Users/index.js'
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

}

Now in `User/index.js` I write the same route logic,

```
export default class IndexUsuario extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div class="top-title">
                        <a href="/users"> User Section</a>
                        <a href="/users/add"> Create new User</a>
                    </div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/users/viewusers" component={ViewUser} /> //import ViewUser from './View.js'
                        <Route path="/users/add" component={AddUser} /> //import AddUser from './Add.js'
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But trying access `users/add` it did not work. Anyone can help me where I'm missing?

Comment: If you are using React Router, take a look at the documentation on nested routing: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Comment: You **must** remove the `exact` prop from `<Route exact path="/users" component={IndexUser} />` or else you will never be able to load any subpage of `/users/`.

Comment: Thanks @LindaPaiste, this works for me

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a second `<Router>` to nest routes. You can nest routes inside each other like this:

```
<Router>
  <Route path="/users" component={UsersRoot}>
    <Route path="/add" component={AddUser} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

When rendering, the `AddUser` component will be passed to `UsersRoot` in the `children` prop.